How to recreate the scratched plastic Lens effect, creating dynamic streaks relative to motion around bright object (sun)?
I need to create a lens effect that happens when the lens has many micro-scratches, creating streaks that seem to appear and disappear while also moving toward and away from the light source when the lens moves relative to it.
I tried creating a lens in Blender and adding a procedural micro bump. Although it produced many dots on the lens, it didn’t produce the streaks nor the effects. It seems I need convolution, but I can’t figure it out.


*video source: MadsHagbarthDamsbo
